# How can I get a differential output as an input for another circuit on ADS?

Tags: oscillator, differential, ads

I'm currently making a project on ADS for a differential pair oscilator:

[image: Oscilator on ADS]

The desired output for this circuit is Vout2-Vout1.Now, I want to plug a buffer on this circuit, but I don't know how to arrange the output in a way that I can pull a wire and input "Vout2-Vout1" into the buffer.

Is it even possible ?

Ps: Excuse any gross mistakes, this is not a professional project.